# Random movement of char in console c#

Tags: c#, random, console, maze

I made a maze game in a console application and by using keys I can control character to leave the maze. Now I want to figure out how to automate that process So that my character can go by random directions and try to find the way out. Here is my class. 
The problem is in the randomMovement Method.

```
class Player: Maze
{
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 1;


    public string playerName;

    public static void printMv() {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {


                Console.Clear();
                mazeDev();

                Console.Write("0");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void movementByUser()
    {

        int x = 1, y = 1;
        while (true)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            mazeDev();
            Console.CursorLeft = x;
            Console.CursorTop = y;
            Console.Write("0");


            ConsoleKeyInfo mv = Console.ReadKey();
            if (mv.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
            if (mv.Key == ConsoleKey.A && mazeBluePrint[y, x - 1] == 0) {
                x--;
            }
            if (mv.Key == ConsoleKey.D && mazeBluePrint[y, x + 1] == 0)
            {
                x++;
            }
            if (mv.Key == ConsoleKey.W && mazeBluePrint[y - 1, x] == 0)
            {
                y--;
            }
            if (mv.Key == ConsoleKey.S && mazeBluePrint[y + 1, x] == 0)
            {
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void randomMovement()
    {
        Random randMove = new Random();

        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;

        int irandom = randMove.Next(4);
        Console.CursorLeft = x;
        Console.CursorTop = y;

        if (irandom == mazeBluePrint[y, x - 1])
        {
            x--;
            printMv();

        }
        else if (irandom == mazeBluePrint[y, x + 1])
        {
            x++;
            printMv();
        }
        else if (irandom == mazeBluePrint[y - 1, x])
        {
            y--;
            printMv();
        }
        else
        {
            y++;
            printMv();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that I want my character to move in random directions to find the way out. Left, right, top, bottom. For example, if on the left is wall then pick another random direction and move to there, and so on.

Comment: @GevorgSahabalyan: That's important information that you should add as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is the direction evaluation. Try this:

```
public static void randomMovement()
{
    Random randMove = new Random();

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    int irandom = randMove.Next(4);
    Console.CursorLeft = x;
    Console.CursorTop = y;

    if (irandom == 0 && mazeBluePrint[y, x - 1] == 0)
    {
        x--;
        printMv();
    }
    else if (irandom == 1 && mazeBluePrint[y, x + 1] == 0)
    {
        x++;
        printMv();
    }
    else if (irandom == 2 && mazeBluePrint[y - 1, x] == 0)
    {
        y--;
        printMv();
    }
    else if (mazeBluePrint [y + 1, x] == 0)
    {
        y++;
        printMv();
    }
}
```

However, this code still has *a lot* of weaknesses (e.g. you could walk out of the boundaries of the `mazeBluePrint` array, which would result in an exception).

---

**EDIT**

If you want to move in the other direction if the first didn't work, you could try something like this:

```
public static void randomMovement()
{
    Random randMove = new Random();
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    Console.CursorLeft = x;
    Console.CursorTop = y;
    while (true)
    {
        int irandom = randMove.Next(4);
        if (irandom == 0 && mazeBluePrint[y, x - 1] == 0)
        {
            x--;
            printMv();
            break;
        }
        else if (irandom == 1 && mazeBluePrint[y, x + 1] == 0)
        {
            x++;
            printMv();
            break;
        }
        else if (irandom == 2 && mazeBluePrint[y - 1, x] == 0)
        {
            y--;
            printMv();
            break;
        }
        else if (mazeBluePrint[y + 1, x] == 0)
        {
            y++;
            printMv();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only moves one time, beginning from 1,1.

Comment: I am not skilled enough to optimize code while writing and giving logic so I know about weaknesses)) The code didn't work. I added ==0 for random to use only free paths for movement and not "walls"